# Which sql statement is faster when counting nulls?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a query to determine if 3 columns are not filled out. Should I make a column in the table just as a flag to note that 3 columns are empty? My instinct tells me that I shouldn't make an extra column. I'm just wondering if I would get any performance boost from doing so. This is for oracle server.

```
select count(*) from my_table t where t.not_available = 1;
```

or

```
select count(*) from my_table t where t.col1 is null and t.col2 is null and t.col3 is null;
```

Comment: What sort of result did you get when you tested it on your system?

Comment: Check the execution plan (btw: using negated conditions as column names isn't such a good idea. In almost all cases using a "positive" flag is easier to understand)

Comment: `select count(*) - count(coalesce(t.col1, t.col2, t.col3)) from my_table t` if datatypes are the same

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing a pre-mature optimization.

Adding an extra column into a table increases the size of each record.  This would typically mean that a table would occupy more space on disk.  Large table sizes imply longer full table scans.

Adding indexes might help.  But, there is an associated cost with them.  If an index would help, you don't need to add another column, because Oracle supports functional indexes.  So, you can index on an expression.

In most cases, your query is going to do a full table scan or full index scan, unless some of the conditions are rare.

In other words, to have a change of really answering your question requires understanding:

- The record layout
- The distribution of values in the three columns
- Any additional factors that might affect access, such as partitioned columns

Answer (score 1):

Only when performance leaves you with no other choice should you resort to an extra redundant column. In this case, you should probably avoid it. Just introduce an index on (col1,col2,col3,1) if performance of this statement is too poor.

Here is an example of why putting the 4th constant value 1 in the index is probably a good idea.

First a table with 1000 rows, out of which only 1 row (456) has all three columns NULL:

```
SQL> create table my_table (id,col1,col2,col3,fill)
  2  as
  3   select level
  4        , nullif(level,456)
  5        , nullif(level,456)
  6        , nullif(level,456)
  7        , rpad('*',100,'*')
  8     from dual
  9  connect by level <= 1000
 10  /

Table created.
```

A row with three NULLS is not indexed by the index below:

```
SQL> create index my_table_i1 on my_table(col1,col2,col3)
  2  /

Index created.
```

and will use a full table scan in my test case (likely a full index scan on your primary key index in your case)

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'my_table')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> select count(*) from my_table t where t.col1 is null and t.col2 is null and t.col3 is null
  2  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 228900979

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |    12 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |    12 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE |     1 |    12 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("T"."COL1" IS NULL AND "T"."COL2" IS NULL AND "T"."COL3"
              IS NULL)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         37  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        236  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        247  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

But if I add a constant 1 to the index:

```
SQL> set autotrace off
SQL> drop index my_table_i1
  2  /

Index dropped.

SQL> create index my_table_i2 on my_table(col1,col2,col3,1)
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'my_table')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then it will use the index and your statement will fly

```
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> select count(*) from my_table t where t.col1 is null and t.col2 is null and t.col3 is null
  2  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

1 row selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 623815834

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE   |             |     1 |    12 |            |          |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| MY_TABLE_I2 |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("T"."COL1" IS NULL AND "T"."COL2" IS NULL AND "T"."COL3"
              IS NULL)
       filter("T"."COL2" IS NULL AND "T"."COL3" IS NULL)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          2  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        236  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        247  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

Comment: +1: You could also add a function-based index on (case when col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null then 1 end) and query on "WHERE case when col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null then 1 end = 1" or course

Answer (score 0):

SQL execution speed depends on numerous factors you didn't list in your question.

Therefore I think you should check the execution plan on your specific server to get first-hand benchmarks of both situtations.

See e.g. [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/displaying_and_reading_the_execution_plans_for_a_sql_statement) for info on how to display the execution plan on Oracle..

Answer (score 0):

If the column(s) in the WHERE clause allow the use of an index then most likely that would be the faster.  However if no columns are indexed then I would expect the first query to be superior.

But checking the plan is the always the best way to know.

Answer (score 0):

I would create on index on not_available and then query that.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (not_available)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you?

```
select count(NVL2(t.col1||t.col2||t.col3),NULL,1) FROM my_table t;
```